# What is optimistic lock in JPA?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am new to JPA. And I came down to this annotation `@Version`.
In the documentation for this annotation it says:

> "This annotation specifies the version field or property of 
>    an entity class that serves as its optimistic lock value. 
>    The version is used to ensure integrity when performing the 
>    merge operation and for optimistic concurrency control. "

What does it mean by optimistic lock and how it is actually related to this annotation?
Thanks

Comment: Find information [under this link](http://bit.ly/Y9IIO1).

Comment: Let everyone edit the same thing at once. When someone commits their change, check whether there have been **other** changes committed since they started their change. If so, cry. (ie. Rollback their changes and force them to get a fresh copy). Usually involves Version numbers as a way to keep track of change sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short...

Each record of an entity with a field annotated as `@Version` is tagged with a version like in SVN. Whenever the entity is updated by commiting (and flushing!) a transaction a check ensures the versions of your current entity and the entry in the database match. A failure in this check results in an `OptimisticLockException`, because someone commited a change on that registry before the current operation did.

Optimistic is based in the concept of

> "I do not need to lock this entry, nobody will touch it"

while a Pessimistic lock actually locks certain operations (Like READ or WRITE) on a given entry assuming

> "Someone will try to update this entity while I work"